# Where can I get a Chinese language word list?

Tags: word, dictionary

I am looking for as large as possible a Chinese language word list. Does anyone know where I could find one?

I want a list on my computer. I am looking into NLP (Natural language processing)

Answer (score 3):

For NLP, I guess you need Chinese word segmentation. A normal dictionary will probably not suffice. You need to look at specialized tools like https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba or https://github.com/lancopku/pkuseg-python

Answer (score 1):

try the 國語辭典, maintained by the ministry of education, taiwan; which is, under cc 3.0.

you can download the excel files here:

https://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/Files/site_content/M0001/respub/dict_reviseddict_download.html

it has about 180,000+ entries, imo, it’s enough for “normal” usage

Comment: hi, I tried this link but it doesn't work (and I am not in mainland China, so it's not because of internet censorship this kind of thing). Yet I am interested in having access to this resource

Comment: @starckman, i just tried from an iOS device, it works  click the link next to “ dict_revised_2015_20210105” anyway, try again 